# GRASS GIS 7, Windows 8.1, Graphical Modeler, Export to Python

Tags: grass-gis, windows

I need help. I´m trying to export my model made in Graphical Modeler in Grass GIS 7.0.0 beta3 to Python Script. The exported file contains only header.

Comment: Hi. It was probably just a temporary bug that is fixed in the following GRASS 7.x versions? Trying to do so with GRASS 7 now seems to work for me.